# Unable to get 'style' of undefined or null reference when overwriting style.display property

Tags: javascript, html, hta

```
<script language="javascript">
 var slideIndex = 0;
 showSlides();

 function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }

 function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
 }

 function showSlides() {
    var i;
    //var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("col", "div", document.getElementById("mySlides"));
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
       slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
 }
</script>
```

I have written this javascript in my HTML and it works fine with it. But when I run it as hta file,

> it throws error "Unable to get 'style' of undefined or null reference
>   when overwriting `style.display` property" at line

```
"slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";"
```

But it did not throw error at line

```
slides[i].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: If `getElementsByClassName` returns an empty HTML collection, your code here looks like it will throw an error. What's the `length` of `slides`?

Comment: Check if salides.length is 0. You are resetting slideIndex to 1. That could cause a undefined

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("col", "div", document.getElementById("mySlides"))` seems to be wrong

Comment: I have set sizes as below:

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple things of interest in here:

1) It looks like you are mixing application logic (HTML) with behaviour logic (JavaScript). You should consider placing this JS code into a file and calling it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>` placed directly above the `</body>` tag. This will run the code after the page loads, so the elements will have rendered before your script runs. If your current script is above the code that renders the element with `id=mySlides`, it could return undefined. Doing this will make your code more modular and easier to read and maintain.

2) I have never seen this syntax before: `document.getElementsByClassName("col", "div", document.getElementById("mySlides"));`. I would consider that highly suspect because I don't see any mention of it at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName. I recommend refactoring your code there. Change it to `document.querySelectorAll('.col, .div, #mySlides')` (assuming you have a class called div. Remove the period if you are trying to find all the `<div>` tags.

3) If you are seeing undefined, slides.length is probably 0 and in my opinion, it's probably related to your getElementById usage. Try adding this right below the `var slides =` part: `console.log("Number of elements found: " + slides.length);`